# How to change numpy array data type to datetime with Null in the array

Tags: python, numpy

```
a = np.array([['2020-01-01',np.nan],[np.nan,'2020-01-08']])
```

I want to change the str data type to datetime64 but remain np.nan as np.nan (the np.nan location doesn't follow any pattern). I tried

```
a.astype('datetime64')
```

but it doesn't work with error message

```
ValueError: Error parsing datetime string "nan" at position 0
```

What should be an efficient way to get the expected output?

Answer (score 0):

It is unclear to me why you want to keep the `np.nans` in the array. In my eyes the `None` value makes more sense in this setting (see [this article](https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/dealing-with-missing-values-nan-and-none-in-python-6fc9b8fb4f31)), after replacing every `np.nan` with `None` `a.astype('datetime64')` works just fine.